# Shiny App: Adding unlimited number of input bars

Tags: r, shiny

I want to build an app in which the user can add as many as input slots as he wants. I could only build an app that let the user to add only one more input slot. Here is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          
                selectizeInput("a", "Something", choices = "blah blah"),
                uiOutput("b"),
                actionButton(inputId = "rm", label = "-"),
                actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "+"),
            ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("test")
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add ,{
    
    output$b <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput("b", "Another thing", choices = "blah blah")
    })
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$rm ,{
    
    output$b <- renderUI({
      
      NULL
      
    })
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have no idea how I can extend this to let the user add as many as input slots as he wants. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try this approach:

We can access new added inputs with `input$a1`, `input$a2` ... `input$ax`

Edit: added an observer to see the new inputs generated in the console. The first input created after pressing `+` button will be called input$a1.

```
  observe({
    print(names(input))
    print(input$a1)
  })
```

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("a", "Something", choices = "blah blah"),
      actionButton(inputId = "rm", label = "-"),
      actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "+"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("test")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  input_counter <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    input_counter(input_counter() + 1)
    insertUI(
      selector = "#rm", where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = div(id = paste0("selectize_div", input_counter()), selectizeInput(paste0("a", input_counter()), label = "Another thing", choices = c("bla", "blabla")))
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$rm, {
    removeUI(
      selector = paste0("#selectize_div", input_counter())
    )
    input_counter(input_counter() - 1)
  })

  observe({
    print(names(input))
    print(input$a1)
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks it works perfectly. What's div doing?

Comment: It wraps the input components to be able to easily identify them when we want to remove them. Actually there's no limit to what the ui inserted can be composed of, it could be a tabsetPanel containing many tabs, so going through each of the id's could be cumbersome. Instead we wrap everything inside a div with a unique id and we can remove everything at once.

Comment: I don't know how to use the new generated input bars because how are you going to call them? input$paste0("a", input_counter()) does not work. And if you first do for example x = paste0("a", input_counter()) then input$x still not works. So how can we use the new input data from these new generated input bars?

Comment: The first input bar will be called a1. To access its values call input$a1. I edited the post and added an observer that outputs in R's console all the inputs available.

Comment: Let's say the user generates 7 input bars and enters an input in the seventh, now I suppose to use that input we should call input$a7 however we cant do that because we don't know beforehand how many input bars will be created by the user so we need a parametric way to call and use it. however input$paste0("a", input_counter()) doesn't work so how are you going to use that future input in the seventh bar?

Comment: For example, you can use `input[[paste0('a', input_counter())]]` to retrieve the value of the last input created.